# Why can't I read EXIF from my loaded UIImage, but still can from NSData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, metadata, exif

I have some EXIF stored in a UIImage that I store using `NSFileManager writeToFile:atomically:`.

Now, when I try to read back the EXIF metadata `imageProperties` here shows the metadata I expect:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);
imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
```

However, if I read the data as a UIImage first, the data is gone:

```
UIImage *writtenImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(writtenImage), NULL);
CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
```

Additionally, even on converting the data variable above to an image, it fails:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
UIImage *writtenImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)UIImagePNGRepresentation(writtenImage), NULL);
CFDictionaryRef imageProperties = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
```

Can EXIF metadata only be ready from the NSData?

Comment: a `UIImage` does not have metadata. An ***image file*** (.png, .jpg, etc) can have metadata - generally retrieved using `CGImageSource`. If you want to make use of the EXIF data, you have to keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXIF is a header for certain image **files** (containers like `png`, `jpg`, `tif`, etc..). When the files are unpacked, the image is a completely different thing - an array of data representing pixels, where EXIF header is no longer relevant. Thus, when you have an `NSData` object of an image **container** it's a completely different beast compared to the image data incapsulated in a `UIImage` object (EXIF header is just not present there).

You can still deduce certain metadata and fill it yourself, but this has nothing to do with `UIImage`, [in this case you just work with the containers (files) directly](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1895/_index.html):

```objc
typedef NS_CLOSED_ENUM(uint8_t, TDWEXIFOrientationValue) {
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueTopLeft = 1,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueTopRight,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueBottomRight,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueBottomLeft,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueLeftTop,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueRightTop,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueRightBottom,
    TDWEXIFOrientationValueLeftBotton,
};

- (void)writeEXIFHeader:(CGImageSourceRef)image {
    /* get the file type */
    CFStringRef UTI = CGImageSourceGetType(image);
    if (!UTI) {
        /* Handle Error Retrieving File Type Accordingly */
        return;
    }

    NSMutableData *imageData = [NSMutableData new];
    /* create an image destination for saving the file */
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)imageData, UTI, 1, NULL);
    if (!destination) {
        /* Handle Error Creating CGImageDestinationRef Accordingly */
        return;
    }

    const void *keys[] = {
        kCGImageDestinationDateTime,
        kCGImageDestinationOrientation,
        kCGImageDestinationMergeMetadata
    };

    TDWEXIFOrientationValue orientationValue = TDWEXIFOrientationValueTopLeft;
    const void *values[] = {
        CFDateCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()), // Sets current date and time for the picture
        CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberCharType, &orientationValue), // Default orientation
        kCFBooleanTrue // merge exif metadata instead of overwriting it
    };


    /* create an CFDictionaryRef with the modified metadata */
    CFDictionaryRef exifData = CFDictionaryCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, keys, values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]), NULL, NULL);

    /* add an image to the destination */
    CFErrorRef errorRef = nil;
    if (!CGImageDestinationCopyImageSource(destination, image, exifData, &errorRef)) {
        CFStringRef errorDescription = CFErrorCopyDescription(errorRef);
        /* Handle Error Creating Writing EXIF data Accordingly */
        CFRelease(errorDescription);
    }
}
```

Comment: Those are [containers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format), not [archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archive_file). And [payload](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payload_(computing)), not "_raw, binary image data_".